# PostgreSQL Functions - Potentially NULL argument Comparison

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have a simplified function defined like so (many columns and parameters removed):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION write_no_duplicates(
      IN p_foreign_key BIGINT
    , IN p_write_value TEXT
    , OUT output my_table
)
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    INTO STRICT output
    FROM my_table
    WHERE my_table.foreign_key = p_foreign_key
    AND (my_table.write_value = p_write_value
        OR (my_table.write_value IS NULL AND p_write_value IS NULL));
EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    INSERT INTO my_table (foreign_key, write_value)
    VALUES (p_foreign_key, p_write_value)
    RETURNING *
    INTO STRICT output;
END $$;
```

The purpose of the function is to write a new row, but prevent duplicates.   We aren't using a unique constraint due to the size & width of the table, and we don't mind if writes are slower.

My question has two parts:

- Is there a better way to perform the null comparison?
- Is there a better way of ensuring uniqueness?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: `my_table.write_value is not distinct from p_write_value`

Comment: If you upgrade to a more current version, you could use `insert ... on conflict` instead which would be much more efficient and it would be safe for concurrent use, which your function is not

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Can i use `insert ... on conflict` without a unique constraint?

Comment: no, but if you want to ensure uniqueness, but a unique constraint is the only sensible way

Comment: Thank you for your help, happy to accept your answer if you'd like to submit one.